# imgly react native implementation

Tags: ios, react-native, photoeditorsdk

I can't seem to get the Photoeditor packages properly imported into my project while following the instructions [here](https://blog.photoeditorsdk.com/photoeditor-sdk-react-native-15179c589a55) and [here](https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/guides/ios/v8/introduction/overview). It doesn't seem to work after trying to install using pods and manually. The issue is that after attempting to install, one or more other packages in my current project become interrupted or mishandled preventing me to launch the application. It disrupts these things usually causing an "Argument too long: recursive header expansion" error in Xcode. This happens only after I try installing. [image]

Comment: I had the same issue when trying to integrate this SDK. I had to clean everything and start fresh to integrate the whole SDK.

Comment: I was actually able to solve it. it had to do with some pod issues and any error associated that wasn't about the sdk were either duplicate issues or packages that were installed that now need minor tweaking.